# npm, node version are different from SSH environment

Tags: node.js, npm, amazon-ec2, ssh, github-actions

I set server app in EC2 AWS
and when I log in SSH server in terminal and check the version of node, npm
I can see them below

```js
npm : 8.11
node : 17.9.1
```

and I tried  CI/CD using github actions and I found out that the versions are different from SSH server in terminal.

```js
cd server
npm -v
node -v

======END======
out: 3.5.2
out: v8.10.0
```

I think they should be the same version but I don't know why they are different.

Am I wrong?

I added some information below
I used actions in workflows below

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash
        working-directory: ./server

    steps:
      - name: Cache node modules
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: ~/.npm
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-node-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-node-
      - name: Use Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '14.x'
          
      - name: executing remote ssh commands using password
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
          username: 'ubuntu'
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
          script : |
            cd server
            pwd
            npm -v
            node -v
```

[image: result image]

[image: result image]

Comment: How did you setup bode version in GitHub action?

Comment: hello I use actions/setup-node@v1 and it shows node version 14 and npm 6
but the step in `executing remote ssh commands using password` shows version 8.10, 3.5.2

Answer (score 0):

I am also experiencing the same issue.
It is because the image which ubuntu 22.04 system uses only supports node.js12.22.
It is technically outdated, but should be supported until the release of Ubuntu 24.04.
Best way is to add command to install node.js in appspec.yml

Comment: So I need to install nvm to use node version?